# How I can I unsource my environment?

Tags: command-line, software-sources, environment-variables

I have source my environment and some environment variables were set, but I need to shift back to my previous environment, how should I do it?
Is there any way to move to the last environment?

Comment: What specifically have you done? What were(if any) the error messages? What commands did you run?

Answer (score 1):

No. You must either close the current shell and open a new one, or use `env` to start a new shell with no environment.